# Validar e-mail com angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Eu tenho o seguinte campo para e-mail:

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" ng-model="fields.email" required="true" />
```

Na div onde está o campo, tenho a seguinte validação:

```
ng-class="{ 'has-error': userForm.email.$error.email }"
```

Acontece que se digitar "abc@abc" é dado como válido, porém como podemos ver está errado.

Já tentei usar expressão regular mas sem sucesso. Como validar e-mails correctamente no AngularJS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize `ngPattern` para alterar o comportamento padrão do Angular:

```
<input type="email" <!-- ... --> ng-model="fields.email" ng-pattern="/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/" />
```

Confira a documentação do Angular para mais informações:

[AngularJS: input[email]](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bemail%5D)

Comment: apenas fiz uma modificação, como a regra de negócio está toda dentro do .js, criei uma variável dentro do escopo e adicionei a expressão regular lá, funcionou perfeitamente com essa.

Answer (score 2):

Na verdade o email abc@abc pode ser válido, da mesma forma que email@localhost.

É incomum, mas é válido tecnológicamente falando, poderia responder a algum endereço.

Podes verificar em:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples

Inclusive não sei como isto vai se comportar com os novos domínios personalizados como .google ou .globo, eles já existem e talvez possam usar emails desta forma, mas aí já não tenho certeza.

Comment: É verdade, mas ainda são incomuns e como você disse, ninguém sabe ainda como vai se comportar com os novos domínios.